# Verificar e Inserir dados em uma Tabela

Tags: php, mysqli

Boa noite, estou implementando um sistema de login por facebook bem básico em meu site, o sistema deveria capturar os dados básicos (id, nome e email) do usuário e guardar em uma tabela e é aí que estou com dificuldades, já rodei muitos fóruns na internet e testei vários códigos, mas nada está funcionando.

---

ATUALIZANDO

---

"Resolvi" o problema inserindo os dados do function.php dentro do fbconfig.php, provavelmente o código deve ficar bem pesado, mas por hora foi o que funcionou:

fbcongig.php

```
<?php
session_start();
// added in v4.0.0
require_once 'autoload.php';
require 'dbconfig.php'; // Conexão com o Banco

...

    /* ---- Session Variables -----*/
        $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;           
      $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = $fbfullname;
        $_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  $femail;      
    /* ---- header location after session ----*/

            if ($fbid>"1"){

                $consulta = "SELECT Fuid FROM Users WHERE Fuid='".$fbid."'";
                $check = mysqli_query($con,$consulta);
                $numeros = mysqli_num_rows ($check);

                if ($numeros <= 0){
                    $query = "INSERT INTO Users (Fuid,Ffname,Femail) VALUES";
                    $query .= "('".$fbid."','".$fbfullname."','".$femail."')";
                    $inserir = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error($con));
                }
            }
    //checkuser($fbid,$fbfullname,$femail);
  header("Location: index.php");
} else {
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email, public_profile,user_friends'));
 header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
}
?>
```

Comment: Tem certeza que deve usar `exit` na função `checkuser` quando encontra um registro na tabela? E por quê a função `mysqli_query`, na instrução `insert` não possui a referência à conexão com o banco `$con`? Aliás, os parâmetros da função `mysqli_query` não na ordem `connection, query`, tipo `mysqli_query($con, $query)`?

Comment: Não, ainda estou estudando sobre... o exit() foi o melhor que havia pensado e já entendi que não foi tão boa ideia, estou modificando o código, mas ainda com muita dificuldade

Comment: Você pode fazer `if ($numeros <= 0) { ...}` e eliminar o `else`, visto que se a condição por positiva, não é executado código algum.

Comment: Isso resolveu o problema das duplicatas, mas os dados não estão sendo inseridos na tabela, está retornando erro nesse trecho
`$sql = "INSERT INTO Users ('Fuid','Ffname','Femail') VALUES ('".$fbid."','".$fbfullname."','".$femail."')";
mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die('Erro ao Cadastrar');`

Comment: E qual é o erro?

Comment: Corrigindo, o erro não é no código que listei, o erro é esse aqui:
`[03-Feb-2017 01:47:42 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: FBID in /home/profissa/public_html/teste/index.php on line 12`

Comment: Pra ser mais exto, a linha 12 agora é ´if ($numeros <= 0){`

Comment: Undefined index faz referencia a algum array...

Comment: Perceba que o erro está acontecendo na linha 12 de `index.php`, não de `function.php`. Veja aí o que há nessa linha.

Comment: No arquivo index.php a linha 12 possui esse código `<?php if ($_SESSION['FBID']): ?>` Que apenas recebe a variável e exibe na tela, estou atualizando a pergunta com todo o código.

Quando tento efetuar o login com uma conta já inserida no bd, as informações aparecem normalmente na tela, porém se utilizo uma conta que não está no bd, retorna a mensagem "Erro ao Cadastrar" no navegador. Como o fbconfig.php redireciona para o index,php, poderia o erro de cadastro não estar enviando os dados para o index, gerando o erro de Undefined?

Comment: Tente fazer nesta linha `if (isset($_SESSION["FBID"]))`

Comment: Tentei aqui o isset, o erro continua sendo o Undefined acima. Como eu disse, quando faço o login utilizando uma conta que já está no bd, tudo funciona corretamente: Os dados são exibidos na tela e não estão sendo duplicados no servidor, o erro só está aparecendo quando tento logar com uma conta que não está no bd... aparece "Erro ao Cadastrar" (e a url fica no "fbconfig.php?code=AQALflYYwz..."), no log do sistema aparece o mesmo erro do Undefined

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta acima, encontrei uma "solução", mas ainda não sei o que poderia estar causando o erro. Agora vou tentar encontrar uma forma de arrumar melhor esse código

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e poste apenas os códigos atuais, já está muito bagunçada.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, acredito que, por hora, o problema está resolvido , estou estudando em como otimizar esse código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua conexão está fora do escopo da função. Por isso o primeiro Notice.

> Notice:  Undefined variable: con in
>   /home/profissa/public_html/teste/functions.php on line 8

Coloque a linha abaixo dentro da função.

```
 $con = mysqli_connect('xxxxxxx','xxxxxx','xxxxxxx','xxxxxxx')
 or die('Não foi possível conectar');
```

OU você deixar a conexão onde esta e pode (não muito recomendado) usar a keyword global, colocando esse código dentro da função:

```
global $con;
```

Sobre escopo de variáveis: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.scope.php

Dê uma olhada na sintax do mysqli_query também http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php , falta um parâmetro antes da string da query:

```
mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )
```

Troca as linhas

```
mysqli_query("SELECT Fuid FROM Users WHERE Fuid='".$fbid."'");
```

por

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Fuid FROM Users WHERE Fuid='".$fbid."'");
```

e

```
mysqli_query($sql,$con)
```

por

```
mysqli_query($con, $sql)
```

Comment: A dica e o artigo em relação ao escopo foram bastante úteis! Fiz algumas alterações, mas ainda não tive sucesso, estou com dificuldades no mysqli_query!

Comment: Vide alterações que fiz na resposta

Comment: Fiz essas alterações mais algumas sugestões do Anderson nos comentários acima, mas ainda estou com problemas, como se a variável `$fbid` não estivesse recebendo os dados. Atualizei minha pergunta inicial com o novo código.